In git, why does my upstream branch keep disappearing?
In git, when I do a checkout of a branch my .git/config file is updated to contain the remote branch (assuming I'm checking out a remote branch).
For example, I checkout a remote branch and view my .git/config file and see the upstream branch is set.
git checkout feature/fixit 

# Verify the upstream was set
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref feature/fixit@{upstream}
origin/feature/fixit

# Double-checking that the .git/config file was updated
cat .git/config
[branch "feature/fixit"]  
remote = origin  
merge = refs/heads/feature/fixit

At some point, I run git pull and get the error no tracking information for the
git pull 

There is no tracking information for the current branch. 

Please specify which branch you want to merge with. 

I know I can run this to fix it.
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/fixit feature/fixit

but . . .
Why does this happen? Why does the upstream branch get removed from my .git/config file?
NOTE: The last time this occurred, the lines for the origin were still in my .git/config yet git complained!
I'm not accidentally editing the file and removing it. :-)
Some sequence of events and commands causes the upstream branch to be removed and I'm trying to track down the reason why this happens.
Please, provide some reasons why this can happen and steps I can use to examine logs on what I've done the next time it happens so that I can know what sequence of events causes this to happen.
Searching for solution

Git branches: tracking upstream - This might be the reason, I am working on two different hosts.

`git fetch` a remote branch - Useful info.


One reason this would happen is if I did the following to update my local branch when git pull fails because the local and remote branches have diverged (because the remote branch was rebased).
git checkout devel
# Delete my local branch so I can update it with the remote branch
git branch -D feature/fixit
    # Deleting my local branch removes the upstream information
git checkout feature/fixit
    # But this adds it back (because push.default=current)

NOTE: I later learned that I can run to do this without deleting my local branch.
git pull --rebase


When you notice the remote tracking branch is gone, does it still exist on the remote repo? (Note you may have to check the history of that branch on the remote repo. If something deletes that branch and something else pushes the branch with the same name again, it could be going away, then coming back, etc.)

For example, we use Pull Requests and always set them to delete the branch after it's merged. All of our local repos are set to prune on fetch. Some people like to re-use the same feature branch name, and in their case the remote tracking branch is consistently deleted, and they just re-push the new version when they wish to.

Could some external process edit the file ? for example: is your repo located in a directory synced with Dropbox or icloud or another service with an active "syncing" daemon ?

@TTT, Good question, and almost always I would say Yes with the caveat that I can't remember for sure to answer this question with 100% certainty.  In some cases it (the origin/feature/fixit branch) has been rebased.

@LeGEC, the working directories are not on any external syncing service so no Dropbox or icloud syncing is being done.
